# Flickering Drop down Menu in IE and Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I have created a drop down menu that I have used on many sites. For some reason in this application (http://quaker.wpengine.com/) the menu flickers and is mispositioned in both Firefox and IE8-10. It works fine in Chrome and Safari. Any idea why this might be happening? I think it is a CSS issue, but can't figure it out for the life of me.

Thanks for the help!

Here is the JS I am using on the menu:

```
//Add necessary classes to navigation
$('ul.level-1 > li > ul').addClass('level-2');
$('ul.level-1 ul > li ul').addClass('level-3');
$('li:has(> ul)').addClass('has-subnav');

// Mobile Navigation
$('body').addClass('js');
var $menu = $('#menu'),
$menulink = $('.menu-link'),
$menuTrigger = $('.has-subnav > a');

$menulink.click(function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $menulink.toggleClass('active');
    $menu.toggleClass('active');
});

$menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
    if ( $(window).width() < 768) {
       e.preventDefault();
    }       

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
}); 

//Remove active class on desktop version
$('ul.level-1 > li').hover(
    function () {
        $('ul.level-1 > li').removeClass('active');
        var $this = $(this);
        if( $this.children('ul.level-2').css('display') != 'none' )  { 
            $this.addClass('active');
        } else {
            $this.removeClass('active');
        }
    },
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if( $this.children('ul.level-2').css('display') != 'none' )  { 
            $this.addClass('active');
        } else {
            $this.removeClass('active');
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Than css i suspect its the problem from Js code which was used for that menu hovering. so have you used any js code for the menu functionality ?

Comment: I am using some JS. Would it be helpful if I paste it in above?

Comment: Ya that would be better  :)

Comment: I need the css for this class `active`, can u provide this

Comment: The only styles for .active have to do with the mobile navigation to add the "+" or "-" sign. I don't think I am using that at all for the drop down navigation. I just have a line of CSS that changes the hidden ul from display none to display block (.js .menu > ul li:hover ul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. I had a stray line of CSS code that somehow got added and said to apply certain styles when you hovered over the `a` attribute in the nav. These styles with the `li` hover styles/JS were conflicting and causing some issues. I removed the line of CSS and we are all good!